# QML how to translate non-user (system) strings?

Tags: qml

I have a project where we use `WebView` object. When there is a error it returns it as a javascript string object, but it is always in english while we need to translate it to our native language. For example, when it fails to load the page it returns a string with "Network access is disabled" content and so our QML browser shows untranslated text.

Comment: Did you try to set a locale?

Comment: @folibis No. Could you tell how to do this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html?

Comment: Basically all you need to do is call qstr for every string you have, and then you will have a separate file that will look the right translation for you.

Comment: You are wrong. If we talk about user string literals in the user code then yes, this is what these things are. But I talk here about a string object and not a string literal, and it is not in my code but inside the Qt itself.